# How to solve ruby on rails pagination paging range issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination, will-paginate

I'm newbie on ruby on rails application, I have already created basic search & pagination which provided by `will_paginate`, but I'm facing the new issue which pagination paging like as,

current situation:

[image: will_paginate pagination]

I need to show pagination number on `1 to 6`, if I click `2 or 3 or 4` then show `7 or 8 or 9`

This is my controller:

```
@post = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).order('post_id DESC')
```

This is my view:

```
<%= will_paginate @post, :previous_label => '<', :next_label => '>' %>
```

How can fix this issue?

Please, I will be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `will_paginate` provides options other than `per_page`. You can try `kaminari` which provides option to control `right` and `left` separately.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `:inner_window` option

```
<%= will_paginate @post, :previous_label => '<', :next_label => '>', , inner_window: 3 %>
```

its default value is `4`. [API documentation](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation#will_paginatecollection-options)

Answer (score 0):

I have will_paginate built into my rails app,
This is how I have it implemented into my app.

**Put this into your gem file:**
    gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'

*bundle install*

**Controller**:

```
@posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).order('post_id DESC')
```

*Note added a s to @posts*

**Your View for the Pagination Bar**

```
<%= will_paginate @posts, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

Hope that works for you